# How can I count all red and green and blue color in Scala language?

Tags: scala, image-processing, rgb

I have problem with count each color RGB from picture. First I load picture from disc and next read this picture. But I con't separate colors and count how many pixels are red, green or blue.

```
    package com.szymonBikowski

import java.awt.Color
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File

import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import com.szymonBikowski.loadImage.getListOffiles
import org.w3c.dom.css.RGBColor

object photoAnalizer {

  var path = "/home/biku/Pulpit/In"
  var correctFile = "/home/biku/Pulpit/In/c.jpg"
  var splitPath = correctFile.split("""/""")
  var filePath = loadImage.getListOffiles(path)
  var filename = splitPath(splitPath.length-1)
  var correctFilePathToSave = "/home/biku/Pulpit/Out/" + filename

//  for (v <- splitPath)
//    {
//      println(v)
//    }
  def photoReader(image: BufferedImage): BufferedImage = {
  var numberOfRed = 0
  var numberOfGreen = 0
  var numberOfBlue = 0
  val lightGreen = new Color(0,255,0)
  val darkGreen = new Color(0,100,0)

  // width and height load photo
    val width = image.getWidth
    val height = image.getHeight

  // create new image with the same size like load photo
    val imageOut = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)

  // copy pixels from load photo(horizontally)
    for (x <- 0 until width)
      for (y <- 0 until height) {
        imageOut.setRGB(x,y, image.getRGB(width-x-1,y) & 0xffffff)

        // count pixels R&G&B
        val color = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y))
        if(isBetween(color, lightGreen, darkGreen))
          numberOfGreen += 1
      }

  imageOut
  }

  def isBetween(color: Color, color1: Color, color2: Color): Boolean = {
    color.getRed >= color1.getRed && color.getRed <= color2.getRed &&
      color.getBlue >= color1.getBlue && color.getBlue <= color2.getBlue &&
      color.getGreen <= color1.getGreen && color.getGreen >= color2.getGreen
  }

  def imageLoad(): Unit ={
    //read heiht and width from load photo
    val photo = ImageIO.read(new File(correctFile))
    val photo2 = photoReader(photo)
  }
imageLoad()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  }




}
```

I try to do this directly colors and next try using compartments as above.
Somone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use getRed(), getGreen(), getBlue() methods from Color class:

```
import java.awt.Color
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage

def photoReader(image: BufferedImage): BufferedImage = {
  // width and height load photo
  val width = image.getWidth
  val height = image.getHeight

  // create new image with the same size like load photo
  val imageOut = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)

  // this is sequence of rgb for each pair x, y
  val rgbs = for {
    x <- 0 until width
    y <- 0 until height
    color = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y))
  } yield (color.getRed, color.getGreen, color.getBlue)
  // here you sum all red, green, blue values for all x, y pairs
  val (numberOfRed, numberOfGreen, numberOfBlue) = rgbs.fold(0, 0, 0){
    case ((sumRed, sumGreen, sumBlue), (red, green, blue)) =>
      ((sumRed + red), (sumBlue + blue), (sumGreen + green))
  }
  imageOut
}
```

UPDATE: 
yield is from ***for-comprehension*** construction. It collects result of loop iterations into sequence (something like list), and you can specify expression what you need to collect. If you need collect rgb-colors, you can collect tuple3 with each color, the result of this code:

```
for {
  x <- 0 until width
  y <- 0 until height
  color = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y))
} yield (color.getRed, color.getGreen, color.getBlue)
```

will be sequence of tuples, where each element is tuple - (red, green, blue) for each pair of (x, y). After that you can sum all tuples using **fold** function. It takes accumulator, in our case is tuple3 with zeros - (0, 0, 0) and adds to it every element of sequence.
if you need get rgb you can end method by rgb tuple and change signature, change function name also:

```
def getRGB(image: BufferedImage): (Int, Int, Int) = {
  ...
  (numberOfRed, numberOfGreen, numberOfBlue)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me "yield - case" construction on my case ? How can I use "sumRed + red" on other method ?

Comment: I filled answer.